# Unit Testing tables with SSDT

Tags: sql, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am looking to do some row counts for a handful of tables after our deployment in our lower level environments. I have a project that deploys a DB to SQL, loads some data into it. I want to validate that the table is now populated with data. I have read the MSDN on creating unit tests but I have a few outstanding questions.

1. Can I only create unit tests against Stored Procs and Functions, or can I simply get a row count from a table or view and Test against that?
2. Can I run multiple "tests" at once? For example, if I want to get the row count for 6 tables, do I need to create a separate test for each table, or can I batch them all together?

Sorry if I missed a large part of the walk through, but the documentation on this was not very helpful pertaining to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. To test a procedure or function, you simplify call that procedure or function and verify result. There is no difference between `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx` statement and `EXEC dbo.Procedure` statement.
2. Yes. In [test conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851223%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) you can specify which **Result Set** to verify. You can also union all row count in single query and use a checksum test condition.